# Making Multiple-Choice problems through Exsheets package

Tags: environments, exam, exsheets, questionnaire

**5-Choice problems through exsheets**

I'm writing a template for multiple-choice problems in the Latex book using exsheets package as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{question}
Sample multiple-choice problem
        \begin{tasks}(4)
            \task Sample answer 1
            \task Sample answer 2
            \task Sample answer 3
            \task Sample answer 4
            \task Sample answer 5
            
        \end{tasks}
    \end{question}

\end{document}
```

The output of the above code for multiple-choice problems isn't a desired output. My desired output is the following image:

[image]

In the above picture, there are some core features for each 5-choice problem:

- Each question has a template like the picture
- Each question is numbered by Chapter number. Question number
- When I insert the command `\hint{some hint about the question}` the hint appears in Chapter Hints, also when I insert `\nohint{}` nothing appears about this question in the Hints chapter
- When I insert `\correctanswer{}` command, the correct choice is specified in the answer key.
- Also, `\answer{}` referees to a complete solution of the question that appears in the Solution chapter
- I want besides some questions there is no star symbol, or one-star symbol or two-star symbol with the following commands: `\nostar{}`, `\onestar{}` `\twostars{}`.

**Yes-No question**

Besides 5-choice questions, at the beginning of each chapter, there are some Yes-No questions like the below image:

[image]

Also, I tried to draw such an answer key template for Yes-No questions and 5-choice questions:
[image]
**If there is an idea with other packages it will be useful.**

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as I could get using tasks.  You could do better with a tabular, or a custom environment.

There are a number of options available with tasks, but none of them seem to do anything useful.  Increasing the label width reduces the indentation, not the answer width.  That seems fixed by the number of columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage{tasks}% redundant
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{question}
Sample multiple-choice problem

    \hfil\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{%
        \begin{tasks}(2)
            \task Sample answer 1
            \task Sample answer 2
            \task Sample answer 3
            \task Sample answer 4
            \task Sample answer 5
        \end{tasks}}
    \end{question}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is an example of using a custom environment to achieve the desired format.  Note that `\choice` puts the text into an argument (unlike `\task` or `\item`).  No attempt was made to save the answer key.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\newcounter{choice}
\renewcommand{\thechoice}{\fbox{\arabic{choice}}}

\newlength{\tempwidth}

\newcommand{\mychoice}[1]{% unlike \tem or task, this choiceuses an argument
  \refstepcounter{choice}%
  \rule[-1.2\dp\strutbox]{0pt}{1.2\baselineskip}% vertical spacing by strut
  \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\thechoice}\hskip\labelsep
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr \tempwidth-\labelwidth-\labelsep}{#1}% answer
  \hskip\columnsep\allowbreak\ignorespaces}

\newenvironment{choices}[1][1]% #1 = number of columns
{\par\medskip% top
  \noindent\hspace{0.1\textwidth}% left margin
  \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}% \textwidth-left and right margins
    \tempwidth=\dimexpr \linewidth+\columnsep\relax% compute width of column
    \count1=#1\relax% make sure it is a number
    \divide\tempwidth by \count1
    \advance\tempwidth by -\columnsep
    \labelwidth=1.4em %note reuse
    \labelsep=0.333em %note reuse
    \let\choice=\mychoice
    \centering}
  {\end{minipage}\par\medskip}% bottom

\begin{document}
    \chapter{}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{question}
Sample multiple-choice problem

    \begin{choices}[2]
      \choice{Sample answer 1}
      \choice{Sample answer 2}
      \choice{Sample answer 3}
      \choice{Sample answer 4}
      \choice{Sample answer 5}
    \end{choices}
    \end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I use a custom environment to achieve the desired template?

Comment: I can't relate your answer to my question.